iPad Pro Gen 3 (2018) Effective USB Bandwidth
I have a rather unique P2P network configuration between an ASUS GU603HM and an iPad Pro 3rd Gen (2018). I'm using usbmuxd to establish an IP over USB connection between the two. I've also tried the same configuration with Apple's own usbmux implementation on a Mac Mini 2018 instead of the ASUS, by enabling network connection sharing (over iPad USB) in Settings.
Although all configurations I've tried allow for higher bandwidth, I'm only getting around 2gbps speed from the laptop/Mac Mini to the iPad, and 3gbps in the reverse direction (from the iPad to the device, tested with iperf3). The iPad should have a USB-C 3.1 Gen 2 port capable of speeds up to 10gbps, and both laptop USB-C ports (Thunderbolt 4, 3.1 Gen 2) and the Mac Mini (Thunderbolt 3) ports are all capable of 10+ gbps. Both cables I've tried are also Thunderbolt.
Well, 2gbps != 10 gbps, and the iPad is the only constant in both systems, so I assume the iPad itself is the bottleneck. My question is this: has anyone been able to get speeds of above 3-4 Gbps on the iPad's USB-C port through means other than monitor output (e.g. file read/write, meaning that network bandwidth is restricted)? Or is some software/hardware in the iPad limiting bandwidth to only a third of what it could be?
